# Ampscript for email with retrieveSalesforceObjects

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to use ampscript for marketing cloud in order to get field opportunity for an email or sms template :

I try with this :

```
    %%[
    VAR @id, @rs, @row, @value
    SET @id= AttributeValue('_subscriberkey') 
    SET @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Opportunity', 'Id, Signature_commercial__c', 'Id', '=', @VariableContainingTheRecordId)
    IF RowCount(@rs) == 1 THEN
    SET @row = Row(@rs, 1)
    SET @value = Field(@row, 'Signature_commercial__c')
    ELSE
    SET @value = 'Fallbackvalue'
    ENDIF
    ]%%

    %%=v(@value)%%
```

But it doesn't work, I don't have an error but %%=v(@value)%% display any value.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

[image: capture ampscript]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code instead of your code

```
 %%[
 VAR @id, @rs, @row, @value
SET @id= AttributeValue('_subscriberkey') 
 SET @con = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Account', 'Id', 'Id', '=', @id)
 IF RowCount(@con)>0 THEN
  SET @rows = Row(@con, 1)
 SET @peid = Field(@rows, 'Id')
 endif
SET @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Opportunity', 'Id, Signature_commercial__c', 'Id', '=', @peid)
IF RowCount(@rs) == 1 THEN
SET @row = Row(@rs, 1)
SET @value = Field(@row, 'Signature_commercial__c')
ELSE
SET @value = 'Fallbackvalue'
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@value)=%%
```